# Percent of Code in DX versus not in DX

Tags: salesforcedx

Query for DX Components:

```
SELECT SubscriberPackage.Name PackageName, count(SubjectId)cmptotal FROM Package2Member WHERE CurrentPackageVersionId IN (SELECT SubscriberPackageVersionId FROM InstalledSubscriberPackage) GROUP BY SubscriberPackage.Name
```

DX components per package (4743)

Script for DX vs Non-DX Apex Code:

```
String endpoint,baseURL = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
endpoint = baseURL+'/services/data/v53.0/tooling/query/?q=SELECT+SubjectID+FROM+Package2Member+WHERE+CurrentPackageVersionId+IN+(SELECT+SubscriberPackageVersionId+FROM+InstalledSubscriberPackage)+and+SubjectKeyPrefix+in+(\'01p\',\'01q\')';
String response; 
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(); 
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID()); 
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
        req.setEndpoint(endpoint); 
        req.setMethod('GET'); 
        Http h = new Http(); 
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);            
        response = res.getBody();     
//        system.debug(response); 
 
Set<Id> apexIds = new Set<Id>();                             
JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(response); 
String CmpCount = '0'; 
while (parser.nextToken() != null) {        
               if((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && ((parser.getText() == 'SubjectID')) ) {               
                              parser.nextToken(); 
                              apexIds.add((Id)parser.getText());
               } 
} 
//system.debug('count='+apexIds);
Integer dx=0,nondx=0;
for(ApexClass a:[SELECT Id, Name, LengthWithoutComments FROM ApexClass 
                 where NamespacePrefix = '' and Status = 'Active' and IsValid = true]){
                     if(apexIds.contains(a.Id)){
                         dx+=a.LengthWithoutComments;
                     } else {
                         nondx+=a.LengthWithoutComments;
                     }
}
for(ApexTrigger a:[SELECT Id, Name, LengthWithoutComments FROM ApexTrigger 
                 where NamespacePrefix = '' and Status = 'Active' and IsValid = true]){
                     if(apexIds.contains(a.Id)){
                         dx+=a.LengthWithoutComments;
                     } else {
                         nondx+=a.LengthWithoutComments;
                     }
}
system.debug('dx='+dx); // dx=6051403 / 10839877  (55.8%)
system.debug('nondx='+nondx); // nondx=4788474     (44.2%)
```

SO this results in:

```
Total DX Artifacts =    4743


    
Apex in DX =    6051403 55.8%
Apex in non-DX =    4788474 44.2%
Total Apex char count = 10839877
```

Is there a way to get components not in DX? My logic is only looking at Apex classes at the moment.

Comment: What are you using "DX" to mean? Components that are members of a package? It looks like you've already successfully queried Apex classes inside and outside packages. What specifically are you trying to do now?

Comment: The logic I have only looks at Apex. I want to know if there is a way to get a count of components in DX versus Happy soup inclusive of Apex etc.

Comment: Thanks for editing to clarify. I just want to push on terminology: components are not "in DX". You're talking about some kind of packaging, probably Unlocked Packages.

Comment: Our company wants to find what %age of metadata is in unlocked packages and what is not. Above is my attempt but I feel the approach is not fully adequate. Sorry for confusion.